# How to translate app name depends on mobile culture in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to translate app name based on mobile culture.
i have seen many sample for that, but in most of the samples, only translate the set of language and assign in resource file.
But i need to translate app name to all mobile supported language.
Is there any solution to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app name should be localized in each platform.

For **iOS**:

> iOS uses a naming standard called Localization Projects or .lproj
>   directories to contain image and string resources. These directories
>   can contain localized versions of images used in the app, and also the
>   InfoPlist.strings file that can be used to localize the app name.

See document here: [localization#app-name-ios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=macos#app-name)

There is also a sample in this thread: [localized-app-name-for-xamarin-ios](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/138179/localized-app-name-for-xamarin-ios)

For **Android**:

> Android follows a different scheme for storing localized images using
>   different drawable and strings directories with a language code
>   suffix. When a four-letter locale code is required (such as zh-TW or
>   pt-BR), note that Android requires an additional r following the
>   dash/preceding the locale code (eg. zh-rTW or pt-rBR).

See document here: [localization#app-name-android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=macos#app-name-1)

> But i need to translate app name to all mobile supported language.

You can add as many as possible resource files of different languages in your project to support the transfer of `all mobile supported language`.

Comment: can we add different languages as manually in project?  like if we have 20 languages, we can add 20 files in project. is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by manually in project? Each language has a corresponding resource file(like I listed in the answer in iOS and Android) in the project.

Comment: @sameer Yes,  if you have 20 languages, you have to add 20 files in project.

Comment: i asked about resource file. for example, if we change the culture as chinese in mobile, should we add chinese app name in project?

Comment: @sameer Sure,  you have to add all the resources file of the languages you want to support in your app. If you does not add one, how does your app transfer the corresponding name that even not exist? BTW, if the answer solves your problem, you can upvote/mark it!